# Firebase notification, application wont open on notification click

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

*I know there are a bunch of question about this topic but my problem is a little bit different.*

I'm using **Firebase** cloud messaging to notify the clients for a certain action. When the app is killed or is in background and as far as I'm on the debug, I can see that when the notification is received by device the **onMessageReceived** method is not being triggered, I have the class
`FCMNotificationIntentService extends FirebaseMessagingService {...}` on which  the method **onMessageReceived** is located and just a default constructor like:

```
  public class FCMNotificationIntentService extends FirebaseMessagingService { 
   
   public FCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    }
        //other methods and stuff...
}
```

so when the notification is received by the device it is not triggering **onMessageReceived** but only the constructor, that means the notification is coming to device without data. Why is this happening, when the app is in foreground the **onMessageReceived** is always being triggered and there are the data given from server.

Any suggestion or idea is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you override onNewToken and do you send a Token to your server to allow communication to the device? In your service class add:

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
}
```

You can refer to this https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/548

Comment: @TaulantLoshi and you are positive your host receives this token and manages it properly when sending out a push? In studio if you go to tools -> firebase -> cloud messaging -> set up cloud messaging, does it say you are connected to Firebase and that FCM is correctly setup in your dependencies?

Comment: yes I did even that, I tried a couple of different ways but still cannot get to trigger onMessageReceived method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working code

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //Displaying data in log
    //It is optional
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    //        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + 
    remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    String message_title = "";
    String from_user_id = "";
    String to_user_id = "";
    String type = "";
    String sound = "";
    String vibrate = "";
    String message = "";

    try {
        message_title = remoteMessage.getData().get("message_title");
        from_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("from_user_id");
        to_user_id = remoteMessage.getData().get("to_user_id");
        type = remoteMessage.getData().get("type");
        sound = remoteMessage.getData().get("sound");
        vibrate = remoteMessage.getData().get("vibrate");
        message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    //Calling method to generate notification

  sendNotification(message_title,from_user_id,to_user_id,type,sound,vibrate,message);
  }
            boolean whiteIcon = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
  Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);


//This method is only generating push notification
//It is same as we did in earlier posts
private void sendNotification(String message_title, String from_user_id,String 
to_user_id, String type, String sound,String vibration,String message) {
 //       Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

 //        if (AppData.getInstance().getReader(this)==null){
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatListActivity.class);
 //        }else {
 //            intent = new Intent(this, ArticlesActivity.class);
 //            
  intent.putExtra(Const.getInstance().iFrom,Const.getInstance().notification);
 //            intent.putExtra("notification",1);
 //        }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= 
    RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new 
    NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
           // .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
            .setContentTitle(message_title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setColor(whiteIcon ? getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary) : 
    getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
    private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean whiteIcon = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return whiteIcon ? R.drawable.notification: R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    }
  // 
   //    }
  }
```